# Как открыть/закрыть форму по клику?

Tags: javascript, css, вёрстка, frontend

Начинающий верстальщик, только учусь. Учебный проект.
Эта форма поиска гостиницы должна открываться/закрываться по нажатию на коричневую кнопку.
Знаю, что это JS, но не могу понять, как это сделать.

Help!

[image: форма]

Answer (score 1):

Если коротко то пишем в html кнопку стилизуем её и это будет высота нашего родителя и скрываем всё что за его пределами....при клике на кнопку делаем высоту автоматически

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $(".item").toggleClass("visible");
})
```

```css
.item {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 70px;
}

.it {
  padding: 40px 0;
}

.item button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  border: none;
}

.visible {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <button>Копка</button>
  <div class="it">
    Здесь форма поиска
    <p>Или ещё какая то информация</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Выше приведенный вариант правильный, но еще можно это сделать без toggle, а просто с помощью добавления класса active, таким образом мы получаем возможность привязаться к этому классу, и узнавать нужную нам информацию, а еще красивую, плавную анимацию. :)

```js
(function( $ ) {
  var object = {
   toggleButton: '.toggle-button',
   formContainer: '.container form'
  };

  $(object.toggleButton).on('click', function() {
   var form = $(object.formContainer);

   if (form.hasClass('active')) {
    form.fadeOut('slow').removeClass('active');
   } else {
    form.fadeIn('slow').addClass('active');
   }
  });
 })(jQuery);
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
 }
 .container {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 }
 .container .toggle-button {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
 }
 .container .toggle-button p {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
 .container form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .container form input:not(:first-child), 
 .container form button {
  margin-top: 10px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="toggle-button">
   <p>Открыть/Скрыть форму</p>
  </div>
  <form>
   <input type="text" name="first_name">
   <input type="text" name="last_name">
   <button type="submit">DONE</button>
  </form>
 </div>
```